# Denied access trying to open process

Tags: c++, windows, memory, process

**Description:** I've gotten myself into a problem, I'm trying to **open a process** and read the memory of that process. It works all fine while debugging in my VS 2013 IDE however, if I build it and run the standalone executable as administrator (or lower credentials) the process cannot be opened properly, I am recieving error code 5, **which is access denied**.

The thing that confuses me is the fact it's working fine in the IDE but not with the standalone executable. I don't see why VS 2013 would have higher credentials than running a program as administrator.

*A link to the code is here:*

```
https://floobits.com/Simple2012/Simple_Bot
The important section is memoryReading.cpp line 30-35
```

**A summary of the problem follows:**
**1.** Everything works fine in visual Studio 2013.
**2.** The standalone executable is denied access when trying to open "the" process.
**3.** The executable is run as with full rights as administrator, so is the IDE.

I want to understand this a bit more detailed so I have two key questions, if anyone is in a good mood, I would love to have a very detailed explanation.
**Question 1:** How can I open the process with my standalone executable?
**Question 2:** Why does this problem occur the way it do?

If there's any information you're missing, don't hesitate to ask for it and I'll add it in as fast as possible. I also tried highlighing some parts to make it more comfortable to read and get a quick and brief idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to open a process and read the memory of that process. It works all fine while debugging

This is because you user account has [`SE_DEBUG_NAME` (`SeDebugPrivilege`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Its common for developers to develop with `SE_DEBUG_NAME`, but its not advised.

You should develop as a regular user account to ensure you don't get these kind of unexpected dependencies.

---

> The thing that confuses me is the fact it's working fine in the IDE but not with the standalone executable...

Now that the issue cleared up...

---

> Question 1: How can I open the process with my standalone executable?
>   Question 2: Why does this problem occur the way it do?

There are a few ways to fix it.

First, you can "compile" the privilege in by setting `/MANIFESTUAC:level=requireAdministrator` in the manifest options. "Compiling the privilege in" is a bit misleading because you will still be prompted by UAC. See [`/MANIFESTUAC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) on MSDN.

Second, you can set *"Run as Administrator"* on the program's properties. Right click the executable, then select the *Compatibility* tab. See [Configure Applications to Always Run as an Administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx) on Technet. You will be prompted by UAC.

Third, you can right click your executable, and then select *"Run as Administrator"*. You will need to do this for each invocation of your program. You will be prompted by UAC.

---

Its not enough to *"Run as Administrator"*. You will now need to enable a privilege or two. That's because Windows does *not* start your process with all privileges enabled (unlike Linux/Unix and `su` or `sudo`). Of the privileges listed at [Privilege Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), these are the three or four interesting ones:

- `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME`
- `SE_DEBUG_NAME`
- `SE_TCB_NAME`
- `SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME`

Here's the code I use to enable privileges, like `"SeDebugPrivilege"`:

```
BOOL CUserPrivilege::EnablePrivilege( LPCTSTR pszPrivilege, BOOL bEnabled ){

    // Returned to caller
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    // Thread or Process token
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;

    __try {

        bResult = OpenThreadToken( GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, TRUE, &hToken );
        if( !bResult )
        {
            bResult = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken );
            assert( TRUE == bResult );
            if( FALSE == bResult ) { __leave; }
        }

        bResult = EnablePrivilege( hToken, pszPrivilege, bEnabled );
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        assert( TRUE == bResult || ( ERROR_SUCCESS == GetLastError() || ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED == dwError ) );

        // We're only enabling one privilege. If we get back
        // ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED, then we failed.
        if( ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED == dwError ) { bResult = FALSE; }
    }

    __finally {
        if( NULL != hToken ) {
            CloseHandle( hToken ); hToken = NULL;
        }
    }

    return bResult;
}

BOOL CUserPrivilege::EnablePrivilege( HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR pszPrivilege, BOOL bEnabled )
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    __try {

        LUID luid;
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES priv;

        bResult = LookupPrivilegeValue( NULL, pszPrivilege, &luid );
        assert( TRUE == bResult );
        if( FALSE == bResult ) { __leave; }

        priv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        priv.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
        priv.Privileges[0].Attributes =
            (bEnabled ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : FALSE );

        bResult = AdjustTokenPrivileges( hToken, FALSE, &priv, sizeof(priv), NULL, NULL );

        // We're only enabling one privilege. If we get back
        // ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED, we failed.
        if( ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED == GetLastError() ) { bResult = FALSE; }

        if( FALSE == bResult ) { __leave; }

        bResult = TRUE;
    }
    __finally { ; }

    return bResult;
}
```

---

You can check what privileges you have with code similar to below:

```
CUserPrivilege::Status CUserPrivilege::HasPrivilege( LPCTSTR pszPrivilege )
{
    // Returned to caller
    Status status = Error;

    // Thread or Process token
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;

    // Scratch
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    __try {

        bResult = OpenThreadToken( GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY, TRUE, &hToken );
        if( !bResult )
        {
            bResult = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken );
            assert( TRUE == bResult );
            if( FALSE == bResult ) { __leave; }
        }

        status = HasPrivilege( hToken, pszPrivilege );
    }

    __finally {
        if( NULL != hToken ) {
            CloseHandle( hToken ); hToken = NULL;
        }
    }

    return status;
}

CUserPrivilege::Status CUserPrivilege::HasPrivilege( HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR pszPrivilege )
{
    // Returned to caller
    Status status = Error;

    // Scratch
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    PBYTE pBuffer = NULL;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* pTokenInfo = NULL;

    __try
    {
        LUID uid = { 0, 0 };
        bResult = LookupPrivilegeValue( NULL, pszPrivilege, &uid );
        assert( TRUE == bResult );
        if( FALSE == bResult ) { __leave; }

        DWORD dwRequired = 0;
        bResult = GetTokenInformation( hToken, TokenPrivileges, NULL, 0, &dwRequired );
        assert( FALSE == bResult );
        if( TRUE == bResult || 0 == dwRequired ) { __leave; }

        pBuffer = new BYTE[dwRequired];
        assert( NULL != pBuffer );
        if( NULL == pBuffer ) { __leave; }

        DWORD dwSize = dwRequired;
        bResult = GetTokenInformation( hToken, TokenPrivileges, pBuffer, dwSize, &dwRequired );
        assert( TRUE == bResult );
        if( FALSE == bResult || dwSize != dwRequired ) { __leave; }

        pTokenInfo = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*)pBuffer;
        DWORD count = pTokenInfo->PrivilegeCount;

        // Status changed...
        status = Missing;

        for( DWORD i = 0; i<count; i++ )
        {
            if( pTokenInfo->Privileges[i].Luid.HighPart == uid.HighPart && 
                pTokenInfo->Privileges[i].Luid.LowPart == uid.LowPart )
            {
                DWORD attrib = pTokenInfo->Privileges[i].Attributes;
                if( (attrib & SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED) ||
                    (attrib & SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT) )
                {
                    status = Enabled;
                }
                else if( (attrib & SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED) )
                {
                    status = Disabled;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        if( NULL != pBuffer ) {
            delete[] pBuffer; pBuffer = NULL;
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

And here's the `Status` enumeration mentioned in the code:

```
enum Status { Missing = -1, Error = 0, Disabled = 1, Enabled = 2 };
```